# How can I call all APCs in a thread's queue?

Tags: c++, winapi

According to [Microsoft's Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-queueuserapc),

> When a user-mode APC is queued, the thread is not directed to call the APC function unless it is in an alertable state. After the thread is in an alertable state, the thread handles all pending APCs in first in, first out (FIFO) order, and the wait operation returns WAIT_IO_COMPLETION.

From what I understand, a single call to `SleepEx(0,TRUE)` should trigger the thread to handle all pending APCs. So I made a small program to test my understanding, but the output was not as I had expected.

The program creates a `WaitableTimer` object that queues multiple function calls of a user-defined function `Triggered()`. The main thread then goes to `Sleep()` for a few seconds, allowing the `WaitableTimer` object to queue multiple calls to the thread.

Upon waking up from `Sleep()`, the main thread then calls `SleepEx(0,TRUE)` to clear the accumulated APCs in the thread queue.(I hope its at a faster rate than the Timer queues New APCS.)The expected result was that `Triggered()` would be called multiple times, but instead it is only called once.

Could someone help me to identify any errors in my concepts or code? Thank you!

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <cassert>

void Triggered([[maybe_unused]] LPVOID lpArgToCompletionRoutine,[[maybe_unused]] DWORD dwTimerLowValue,[[maybe_unused]] DWORD dwTimerHighValue)
{
    printf("TRIGGERED!\n");
}

int wmain()
{
    HANDLE hTimer{ ::CreateWaitableTimerW(nullptr, TRUE, L"MyTimer") };
    assert(hTimer);

    SYSTEMTIME st{};
    FILETIME ft{};
    st.wYear = 2020;
    st.wDay = 15;
    st.wHour = 15;
    st.wMonth = 10;
    st.wMinute = 15;

    ::TzSpecificLocalTimeToSystemTime(nullptr, &st, &st);
    ::SystemTimeToFileTime(&st, &ft);

    LARGE_INTEGER dueTime{};
    dueTime.QuadPart = *(LONGLONG*)&ft;//<<<<< I've also tried setting a relative lpDueTime value

    assert(::SetWaitableTimer(hTimer, &dueTime, 100, Triggered, nullptr, FALSE));
    ::Sleep(1000);

    ::SleepEx(0,TRUE);

    /* I also tried the following to replace ::SleepEx(0,TRUE)
    ** DWORD ret{WAIT_IO_COMPLETION};
    ** while (ret == WAIT_IO_COMPLETION)
    ** {
    **   ret=::SleepEx(0, TRUE);
    ** }
    */
     
    assert(::CancelWaitableTimer(hTimer));  
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you read the [SetWaitableTimer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/synchapi/nf-synchapi-setwaitabletimer) documentation:

> If the timer is set before the thread enters an alertable wait state, the APC is canceled.

This means that the APC will only be queued while your thread is actually in a waitable state, i.e. when `SleepEx()` or a similar function is running. So during your `Sleep(1000)` the timer did trigger, but the APC was never queued.

If you change your code to always only use `SleepEx()`, then it'll "work":

```cpp
    auto now = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    auto timeout = now + std::chrono::seconds{ 1 };
    while (now < timeout) {
        DWORD timeoutMs = static_cast<DWORD>(std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(timeout - now).count());
        ::SleepEx(timeoutMs, TRUE);
        now = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    }
```

(`#include <chrono>` at the top and remove the `Sleep(1000)` and `SleepEx(0, TRUE)` calls. You can use WinApi instead of `std::chrono` for the same logic, but I like `std::chrono` here due to its simplicity.)

But if you do anything other than `Sleep(1000)` during which you want your timer to execute, e.g. perform some calculations or similar, then what you want to do will simply not work.

Honestly I'd recommend against using APCs anyway - timers created by `CreateWaitableTimerW()` can be integrated into a standard event loop (`WaitForMultipleObjectsEx`/`MsgWaitForMultipleObjectsEx`-based), that's probably the easiest way to do this.

If on the other hand you want to be sure that no timer event is ever dropped, then start another thread in the background that mainly just sleeps, but periodically wakes up, and then either directly executes the code you need, or queues a callback in the main thread every time a timer event occurred. (Which queuing mechanism you'd want to use would depend on how your main thread is organized.)

Comment: all is wrong, both msdn and your answer. apc not canceled and inserted. but exist only single apc

Comment: I'll try to have the documentation clarified. It's trying to say "If the timer is set **again** before the thread enters an alertable wait state, the **first** APC is canceled."

Comment: @RaymondChen - it not canceled. exist only single embeded (to `ETIMER`) APC . and APC can be inserted only once. after it inserted and before removed - it can not be inserted again. the state of thread - here unrelated at all. APC will be inserted, if timer signal and yet not inserted, independed from thread state

Comment: @RbMm Right, technically it is reused, but there is no public way of talking about APCs that way. The external behavior is as if the old one were canceled.

Comment: @RaymondChen -i at all not understand what is mean under *APC is canceled.* - this is how ?! i know what is IRP canceled for example. but APC can not be canceled at all. it can be inserted to thread or not inserted. here the root - timer not allocate new APC every time when it signaled, but reuse the same embeded APC member

Comment: From the programmer's point of view, the first APC never arrives. It's as if it were magically canceled. Maybe better terminology would be to say that the APCs are *coalesced*.

Answer (score 0):

system allocate single `KAPC` object, related to timer. the `KAPC` can be inserted to thread only once. if APC already inserted to thread - it can not be inserted second time. until will be not removed. during `Sleep(1000);` timer signaled several times, but only on first signal APC will be inserted. and when you call `SleepEx(0,TRUE);` this apc delivered

Comment: @bugger [`_KAPC`](https://www.nirsoft.net/kernel_struct/vista/KAPC.html) this is concrete structure - look it definition in `wdm.h` . look at `Inserted` member - struct can be inserted to thread only single time. when you create timer - [`ETIMER`](https://www.nirsoft.net/kernel_struct/vista/ETIMER.html) is allocated and `TimerApc` used as APC to insert. it embeded and single. after it inserted and not removed - new will be not inserted